# Two-way replication between MongoDB and DynamoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, replication

We certainly want to use separate databases since the front-end team finds it robust to work with MongoDB Atlas and AWS cloud architects find it easy to work with DynamoDB.

**Our architecture**:

- Web application uses MongoDB to insert, update and retrieve data.
- The MongoDB is synced in real-time with DynamoDB.
- Background AWS services use DynamoDB for inserting, updating and retrieving data.
- The changes in either DynamoDB or MongoDB are replicated to each other.

**Tried so far**:

- We currently do have a sync in place with DyanmoDB streams and MongoDB atlas trigger to listen to changes on each database and forward them to the other. We use lambas for this, but our replication logic is not robust yet.
- AWS Database Migration Service with ongoing replication has been suggested but haven't been able to get it to work in our use case. Perhaps, this is one option.
- 3rd party services like: https://www.cdata.com/sync/

**Ideal Fit**

The most ideal solution would be an AWS-based solution if not a reliable 3rd party service.

Greatly appreciate any resources or thoughts on this! :)

Comment: I doubt there is an ideal fit, if I was you I would question the solution, database sync in the real time is not a trivial task. But if you want to go down that path I would continue exploring DMS with a continuous replication from Mongo to DDB. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/performing-a-live-migration-from-a-mongodb-cluster-to-amazon-dynamodb/ and for the DDB to Mongo I would continue using DBSteams+Lambda but again as you mentioned it's going to a flaky unless lots of effort is put

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd yep, going for AWS DMS for a one-way sync and lambda for DBB to MongoDB sync is one option. Any particular reason why you say it would be flaky? I believe the only problem arises when the time between operations on same document is less than 100ms say, where it might confuse the system?

Comment: what will happen when a record from mongodb is being inserted into DDB, the same record will appear in the stream again to be inserted into back to mongo ? you will have to rely on some sort of flags or indexes ? either way, it's your system to build but I personally can't image this to be a production grade solution

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd Right, such cases are what I'm concerned too. The lambda will serve as a bottle neck to prevent infinite insert loops. Essentially we'd have to check if the new and old document match. A bit hacky but not sure what else we can do about this sync for production-grade :(

Comment: consider how much time/money you will spend building this then supporting, and the quality of the outcome. While it sounds like a fun task to play with, ask stateholders why they need master to master life replication across two independent systems ? May be thats not what you need at the end of the day, and some sort of daily batch import will be sufficient